# X11 libraries in OSX 10.5?

Tags: macos, installation, x11

I have (I believe) a fairly standard 10.5 installation, and I'm trying to compile.. Well, I'm trying to compile T.38modem, which requires OPAL which requires pwlib which requires libX11. Kinda dumb, but whatever.

The problem is that in /usr/X11/lib, I have the following:

```
Brians-mini$ nol libX11.*
lrwxr-xr-x 1 root wheel 14 Mar 3 2008 libX11.6.2.0.dylib@ -> libX11.6.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x 1 root wheel 18 Feb 20 17:53 libX11.6.dylib@ -> libX11.6.2.0.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x 1 root wheel 14 Feb 20 17:54 libX11.dylib@ -> libX11.6.dylib
```

Anyone see anything odd with that?

So, where am I supposed to get libX11.dylib? (or .6.2.0.dylib, or whatever)

Edit response to a comment: otool gives:

```
X11:
    /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation (compatibility version 150.0.0, current version 476.15.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/Versions/A/SystemConfiguration (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 212.2.0)
    /usr/X11/lib/libXau.6.dylib (compatibility version 7.0.0, current version 7.0.0)
    /usr/X11/lib/libxcb.1.dylib (compatibility version 2.0.0, current version 2.0.0)
    /usr/X11/lib/libX11.6.dylib (compatibility version 9.0.0, current version 9.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 111.1.1)
```

Comment: Your otool looks normal, and seems to have found libX11.6.dylib. Can you run X11 successfully?

In any event, at this point I'd try installing the macports libx11... it will go into it's own spot in /opt, so it won't collide with Apple's X11.

Comment: *nix dependency chains drive me insane (yeah, yeah, short drive, I know)...  :-) It's one of the biggest stumbling blocks to wider *nix adoption.

Comment: HAHAHAHA... "yeah, yeah, short drive, I know"... I needed that :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that at some point X11 wasn't set up right, then I tried to install it from Fink, then all hell broke loose. I did a rm libX11.*.dylib and re-installed X11 from disk and now at least pwlib seems to be installing...

Answer (score 1):

X11 is an optional install on the Leopard install DVD.

[Using X11 in Mac OS X](http://docs.info.apple.com/article.html?path=Mac/10.5/en/8699.html)

*EDIT:*

[From:](http://developer.apple.com/opensource/tools/X11.html)

> "The X11 SDK headers are available as
>   part of the Xcode Developer Tools."

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Well, that's pretty cute! :-)

I've had a look on both my machine as well as the machine of a colleague in marketing who has a plain (just hit "install") Leopard install with no dev tools. Both of us have /usr/X11/lib (I think it is installed by default now with Leopard).

Interestingly, both of us also have a libX11.6.dylib that does not merely point in a circular loop:

```
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel       14  3 Mar  2008 /usr/X11/lib/libX11.6.2.0.dylib -> libX11.6.dylib
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  4620928 31 Jul  2008 /usr/X11/lib/libX11.6.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel       14  3 Mar  2008 /usr/X11/lib/libX11.dylib -> libX11.6.dylib
```

Would you mind having a look at your X11.app and seeing where it points? I'm wondering if there's a corruption or some other goody:

```
$ cd /Applications/Utilities/X11.app/Contents/MacOS
$ otool -L X11
```

You should see something like:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation (compatibility version 150.0.0, current version 476.15.0)
/System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/Versions/A/SystemConfiguration (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 212.2.0)
/usr/X11/lib/libXau.6.dylib (compatibility version 7.0.0, current version 7.0.0)
/usr/X11/lib/libxcb.1.dylib (compatibility version 2.0.0, current version 2.0.0)
/usr/X11/lib/libX11.6.dylib (compatibility version 9.0.0, current version 9.0.0)
/usr/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
/usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 111.1.1)
```

You may be able to re-install just the X11 part from the Leopard disks, though if you've upgraded to 10.5.x a 10.5.0 disk may not let you install even just that piece. Not sure. Are you on an Intel mac? If so, someone (like me) could probably just send you the darn file, though it may not fix the issue if X11 has been seriously corrupted for some reason.

**EDIT**: It seems MacPorts also has an xorg-libX11 portfile that you could install if that's easier: http://trac.macports.org/browser/trunk/dports/x11/xorg-libX11/Portfile